# jquery set input val() and return the parent html() get empty input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a function to input some field and return the html to show:

```
function get_goodinput(GoodsSn, InCount, SellCount, Barcode, SinglePrice, BatchNo) {
    var $c = $('#t_addgoods_table').clone();
    $c.children("form").attr("id", "addgoods_form"); //id="t_addgoods_table"

    var $f = $c.children("form");

    $f.find("input[name='BatchNo']").val(BatchNo);
    $f.find("input[name='SinglePrice']").val(SinglePrice);
    $f.find("input[name='Barcode']").val(Barcode);
    $f.find("input[name='SellCount']").val("sssssssssssssssssssssss");
    alert($f.find("input[name='SellCount']").val());
    //this step can get the val..

    $f.find("input[name='InCount']").val(InCount);
    $f.find("select[name='GoodsSn']").val(GoodsSn);

    return $c.html();
}
```

and show in the [metroUI dialog](http://metroui.org.ua/dialog.php)

```
$('#addgoods').click(function (e) {
    $.Dialog({
        'title' : '添加商品',
        'content' : get_goodinput("aaa", "aaa", "", "12", "12312", "aaaaa"),
        'draggable' : true,
        'buttonsAlign' : 'right',
        'closeButton' : true,
        'position' : {
            'zone' : 'center',
            'offsetY' : 100
        },
        'buttons' : {
            '确定' : {
                'action' : function () {
```

but I always get the empty input...why???

[image]

The HTML code:

[image]

Comment: trying returning the value with val() instead of html()

Comment: what is `$('#t_addgoods_table')` ? If it is a `table` element, it can't have a form as `children()`

Comment: @charlietfl yes, this is the table element in the html, and the form in the table.. i copy the table and put it in to the dialog... it seems no problem with that..

Comment: @JavierBrooklyn   no, its not useful..  it can only return html() for the element.. val() is nothing return..

Comment: The `value` attribute isn't updated in the HTML (which is what the `html()` method returns), it's updated in the DOM, as a property of the `HTMLInputElement`, so, as Javier suggests, use `val()`.

Comment: @DavidThomas but...how can i get the value in the table element? the $c is a table element..

Comment: Here's a thought, then: *show us your HTML*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form can't be a child of table, only elements like `tr,tbody,thead,tfoot` can be children.

If form is inside table it has to be in a `TD` so you can use `find()` instead of `children()`

You are also likely to have invalid html going into the dialog since you are putting the inner html of the table and not the whole table into a non table element. `html()` method takes the innerHtml of an element.

You could wrap the table in a DIV and insert the table compeletly:

```
return $('<div>').append( $c ).html();
```

Comment: you need to post html , usually form would wrap table

Comment: = = the html code is large ... hard to post , i only post a screenshot .. plz see it ..  http://i.stack.imgur.com/vW7xT.png

Comment: ahhh  is not a table so code would work but....  updating value does not show up in the html. Dialog you are using is not ideal since it doesn't give you DOM elements you can append to for content. Taking the html of a completed form doesn't work

Comment: wouldn't have this sort of problem with a dialog like jQueryUI since you can append the form as DOM element (along with all it's properties and values) and not need to put it as raw html string

Comment: yes = =  im sorry.. this is not a form  in the table.. i wrong..   so it is no method to return `html()` string for set `val()`?

Comment: this dialog is not very code firendly... switch dialogs...you can adjust style for another one to match if needed. Ones that use existing elements will give you more freedom. For example jQueryUI has very robust dialog and you can append the form like `$('#dialog').html( $c.find('form').clone(true))` and would keep it;s properties and also event handling

Comment: Also the [`colgroup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/colgroup) element can be a child of the `table` (and this can contain only the [`col`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/col) element, I think; though that might be a lack of sleep coupled with long day at work making the MDN docs confusing to me right now).